# Close activity after perfoming

Tags: android, android-activity, parent

I have an Activity A, which starts activity B, which starts activity C. When I press back button I want go back to the Activity A. Instead, activity B is always opened (as a popup thanks to the style) after pressing back on activity C.

I try with meta-data following android doc but i can't solve my issue.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.A"
            android:label="@string/ActivityA"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.B"
            android:label="@string/ActivityB"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.C"
            android:label="@string/ActivityC" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.test.A"/>
        </activity>
```

Comment: before calling Activity C.. first `finish()` Activity B then call Activity C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way.

```
...
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class));
...
```

Comment: @BSOD Pleasure helping you.

Answer (score 0):

After you start activity C from Activity B call finish();  It will remove B from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Finish activity `B` when starting activity `C` from it